# Apache EntityUtils toString from HttpResponse blocks thread indefinitely

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x, java-17

Code:

```
public static String stringFromHttpResponse(HttpResponse response) throws IOException {
    if (isStatusOk(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode())) {
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        if (entity != null) {
            return EntityUtils.toString(entity);
        } else {
            throw new IOException("HttpResponse has a null entity");
        }
    } else {
        String err = String.format("HttpResponse status code is not Ok(code=%s, reason=%s)",
                response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode(), response.getStatusLine().getReasonPhrase());
        throw new IOException(err);
    }
}
```

Output from jstack:

```
 "main" #1 prio=5 os_prio=0 cpu=8114.46ms elapsed=1102.01s tid=0x00007f897c0256e0 nid=0x66a6 runnable  [0x00007f89830a1000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read0(java.base@17.0.2/Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(java.base@17.0.2/SocketDispatcher.java:47)
        at sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.tryRead(java.base@17.0.2/NioSocketImpl.java:261)
        at sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.implRead(java.base@17.0.2/NioSocketImpl.java:312)
        at sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.read(java.base@17.0.2/NioSocketImpl.java:350)
        at sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl$1.read(java.base@17.0.2/NioSocketImpl.java:803)
        at java.net.Socket$SocketInputStream.read(java.base@17.0.2/Socket.java:966)
        at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.streamRead(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:137)
        at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.read(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:197)
        at org.apache.http.impl.io.ContentLengthInputStream.read(ContentLengthInputStream.java:176)
        at org.apache.http.conn.EofSensorInputStream.read(EofSensorInputStream.java:135)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(java.base@17.0.2/StreamDecoder.java:270)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(java.base@17.0.2/StreamDecoder.java:313)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(java.base@17.0.2/StreamDecoder.java:188)
        - locked <0x0000000476808f38> (a java.io.InputStreamReader)
        at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(java.base@17.0.2/InputStreamReader.java:177)
        at java.io.Reader.read(java.base@17.0.2/Reader.java:250)
        at org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils.toString(EntityUtils.java:227)
        at org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils.toString(EntityUtils.java:308)
```

This happens sporadically and I am not sure what's triggering this state. I have tried adding timeouts at the HttpRequest level but it's not helping. This is apache httpclient 4.5.13

Comment: Do you have a finally block in call method that close the response and close the httpclient connection? 
If yes can you post the entire method?